# Send message to all open clients in browser when they're logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got a website in ASP.NET MVC 3.

People can send messages to other peoples inbox and at the moment the only way they get notified is when they a) login, b) do a refresh with post back c) through mail.

But how do I get to send a notification to the right person (httpcontext.identy.user.name is unique if that helps?) and post it on their screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use WebSockets to push new messages to all users or use ajax polling and check for new messages at a regular interval.

The easiest way would be to implement this using [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR), which uses WebSockets or defaults to long polling if WebSockets is not available.

I would recommend going through the SignalR [Getting Started](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Getting-Started) guide. There is also a sample which is available via Nuget, named `SignalR.Sample`.

Comment: Yeah, i'd try SignalR for this.